# React - wait for div to load fully

Tags: reactjs

So Im fetching some messages from DB and then I'd like to show them in a chat div. Here's the code:

componentDidMount():

```
socketio.on("message", function(data) {
  // socketio is initialized outside of class
  // and the server emits "message" on client connection
  that.setState({
    // before this happens, there is no "messages" var in state
    messages: data
  });
});
```

render():

```
<div class="chatbox">
{messages &&
 messages !== undefined &&
 messages.length > 0 ? (
 messages.map(function(item, i) {
           if (item.from === uid) return <div class="message-incoming">{item.body}</div>;
           else return <div class="message-outgoing">{item.body}</div>;
    })) : (
        <></>     
    )
}
</div>
```

The message get loaded into a div with class "chatbox". What I would like to do is to wait for these messages to get rendered and after that manually scroll the "chatbox" to bottom, so users can see latest messages. But so far I haven't figured out a way to make this work, because no matter what code I try, it gets triggered before map finishes and not after. Basically I would like to do:

```
document.getElementById("chatbox").scrollTop = 
    document.getElementById("chatbox").scrollHeight;
```

But no matter where i execute this code, scrollHeight is always the same as initial height of "chatbox", because the line gets triggered before all messages are rendered. I want to trigger it after the div is completely loaded.

Any ideas?

Comment: Would you mind providing more of your code?

Comment: @Rallen could you be more specific? what parts of code would you like to see? the first code snippet is taken from inside of render() method of my component. The second snippet is the code I would like to use, but I don't know how to connect it. The variable messages is taken from state - I fetch my endpoint and save results in state under "messages".

Comment: The code of your component, if you would mind.

Comment: I added everything that's in any way related to my question.

Comment: Sorry if I ask again, but would you mind providind the **complete** code of your component, from `class ... extends Component` until the end.

Comment: Sorry, but no, because it has 350 lines of code, but mostly because there is not a single connection to my question in the rest of the code. If something is not clear to you, feel free to ask me and I will gladly provide you with more information here in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Just return null if  `messages` is not yet populated:

```
render() {

    if(!this.state.messages) return null;

    <div class="chatbox">
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the [`componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) to scroll to the bottom.

> `componentDidUpdate()` is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.
>
> Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM when the component has been updated. [...]

```
class ChatComponent extends Component {

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (prevState.messages.length != this.state.messages.length) { // Or any other comparison
            document.getElementById("chatbox").scrollTop = document.getElementById("chatbox").scrollHeight;
        }
    }

    /* ... */
}
```